# How do I recompile libav on ubuntu 12.04 without breaking anything

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, pulse-audio, libav

I have a "Little" script for screencasting - I'll skip to the good part.

In my avconv command I record 3 different sources simultaneously to 3 different tracks. The only way I know of getting audio from pulseaudio is like so:

```
-f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse
```

Unfortunately, this results in 3 identical entries in the "Recording" tab of pavucontrol. Looking at the man page there should be an option to record like so:

```
-f pulse -ac 2 -i <devicename> -name <trackname>
```

Unfortunately, it requires installation of `libpulse-simple` which I can't find on my system or in my repository.

Is there a way to have a `name` like option using `-f alsa`?

If not, how do I get `libpulse-simple` installed on (x)ubuntu 12.04?

**Edit:** It looks like [the ubuntu version is compiled wrong](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135682/avconv-x11grab-issues-unable-to-find-a-suitable-output-format-for-pulse#answer-136498) (yet again)

The question is now "How do I compile this without breaking my system"

I would like the presets available in `/usr/share/avconv` to stay available and be able to revert with the package manager (So no dirty hacks like dumping it in `/opt`)

**Edit2:** I've compiled avconv with libpulse enabled, but now x11grab is missing! I can't find a list of `./configure` options but I want to enable everything I possibly can so I don't have to deal with missing feature after feature. Anyone know where to find such a list? How about whatever args they use for the official ubuntu packages?

Comment: I'm not on Ubuntu so I can't help much, but is that in `libpulse-dev` maybe?

Comment: Nope, installing it still gives me `Unknown input format: 'pulse'`

Comment: You'd have to recompile Libav/FFmpeg in order to have it recognize that with `--enable-libpulse` I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to see what is needed to replace my defaults without breaking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it has compiled properly like so:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix="/home/j/projects/avconv-source/build" --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libpulse --enable-libx264 --enable-x11grab
```